# If a language is undecidable, then its complementary language must also be undecidable?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability, decidability, turing-recognizable

Reference from here [If a Language is Non-Recognizable then what about its complement?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6167/if-a-language-is-non-recognizable-then-what-about-its-complement)
There exist complementary languages of unrecognizable languages that are recognizable, and there exist complementary languages of unrecognizable languages that are undecidable.

If a language is unrecognizable, then it must be undecidable.

If a language is undecidable, then its complementary language must also be undecidable?

Answer (score 1):

If $A(x)$ is an algorithm deciding $x\in L^c$, then $\lnot A(x)$ is an algorithm deciding $x\in L$.

To be more pedantic, by $\lnot A(x)$ I mean the algorithm that executes $A(x)$ and if that accepts (resp. rejects) then it rejects (resp. accepts). In a programming language it's likely something like `bool not_a(string x) { return not a(x); }`.

Hence, if $L^c$ is decidable then $L$ is such.

Using a similar argument you can prove that $L^c$ is decidable if and only if $L$ is such.